# Two columns in alltt environment

Tags: environments, two-column

How do I make two columns in an `alltt` environment??

```
\begin{alltt}
\hlkwd{options}\hlstd{(}\hlkwc{BingMapsKey} \hlstd{=} \hlstr{"clave de acceso de Bing"}\hlstd{)}

\hlcom{## código para Bing}
\hlkwa{for} \hlstd{(c} \hlkwa{in} \hlnum{1}\hlopt{:}\hlkwd{nrow}\hlstd{(cemento.dist.mta)) \{}
    \hlstd{cemento.dist.mta}\hlopt{$}\hlstd{Distancia[c]} \hlkwb{<-} \hlkwd{try}\hlstd{(}\hlkwd{georoute}\hlstd{(}\hlkwd{c}\hlstd{(cemento.dist.mta}\hlopt{$}\hlstd{origen[c],}
        \hlstd{cemento.dist}\hlopt{$}\hlstd{destino[c]),} \hlkwc{verbose} \hlstd{=} \hlnum{TRUE}\hlstd{,} \hlkwc{returntype} \hlstd{=} \hlstr{"distance"}\hlstd{,} \hlkwc{service} \hlstd{=} \hlstr{"bing"}\hlstd{))}
\hlstd{\}}
\end{alltt}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, but the question is unclear. What should `\hlwkd` `\hlstd` `\hslstr` produce? And what should go in one column and in the other?